# Is it possible to use setTextureRect on CCAnimation in Cocos2d (cocos2d-x)?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am using `setTextureRect`on `CCSprite` each frame, so it looks like it is being masked, etc..

I wanted to do the samething for a sprite with an animation, but it doesn't work, animation just disappears... Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible I think.

```
CCAnimation::addSpriteFrame(CCSpriteFrame *pFrame)
```

is used to add frame to animation manually.

And you can create the CCSpriteFrame by

```
CCSpriteFrame::createWithTexture(CCTexture2D* pobTexture, const CCRect& rect)
```

or

```
CCSpriteFrame* create(const char* filename, const CCRect& rect)
```

It should be the same as you create a CCSprite.